# Installing spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-2.2.0.jar in my Spark environment

Tags: apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr, amazon-kinesis

I am using an EMR cluster to develop/run Spark jobs. Now I need to access Kinesis and need to install spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-2.2.0.jar. I am not very clear on how to do that yet. Any pointer/experience will be very helpful

Comment: can you please share that .jar file with the community?

Comment: probably this one, for who is interested
https://github.com/giaosudau/surge/blob/master/src/main/resources/spark-sql-kinesis_2.11-2.2.0.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up building it myself from the source code (github) and then specified it in my spark-submit code. That seems to be recommended.